# How to build this query on Symfony with QueryBuilder?

Tags: symfony, query-builder, symfony4

Please I am a beginner on symfony and I have 2 entities: `category` and `professionnal` with ORM many to many. And 'City' is an entity with ORM oneToMany with 'professionnal'.
In `professionnel` I have a property `city`. I want to show `professionnal` grouped by `categories` who have a special `cityId` putted on parameter in the url. 
I put this query on sql

> (for example city_id= 10873)

, it gives me the results.

```
SELECT * FROM sub_category AS a LEFT JOIN professionnel ON professionnel.city_id = 10873
```

but I don't know how to write with querybuilder.

I put this solution but I have errors:

```
$city  = $paramFetcher->get('city');

$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository(SubCategory::class)
                    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Professionnel','p')
                    ->where('p.city = :city')
                    ->setParameter('city', $city);


return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

in log:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.name AS name_1 FROM category c0_ LEFT JOIN professionnel p1_ WHERE p1_.city_id = ?' with params ["10873"]:  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p1_.city_id = '10873'' at line 1"
```

I search on forums too and I found that I can replaced the 'ON' of leftJoin as following, but shows me all professionnals:

```
$city  = $paramFetcher->get('city');

$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository(SubCategory::class)
                                        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
                                        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Professionnel','p','WITH','p.city = :city')
                                        ->setParameter('city', $city);
return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

For the mapping, I put it like this:

```
class Category
{
/**
     * Many professionnels have Many categories.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Professionnel", mappedBy="Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="professionnel_category")
     */
    private $professionnels;
}
class Professionnel extends User
{
/**
     * Many professionel have Many categories.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="professionnels")
     * @Groups({"Default", "professionnel", "user"})
     */
    private $categories;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What errors do you have? What query does this generate?

Comment: I am quite confused on the `leftJoin` part. Shouldn't you be joining `Professionnel` with `Category`?

Comment: @TomášVotruba : I'm getting the following error: Cannot access private property Error::$previous

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming that you have your entity relation set up correctly (**please update your question with those**), I see one mistake above.

If you look at the official [`Doctrine Query Builder`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html) documentation, the `leftJoin` method's third argument is either `WITH` or `ON` constant and not join predicate. That one comes as a 4th argument. But, even then, that join predicate is only used is a very specific use-case, where you want to further define your join relation. By looking at your example, I doubt that is your case.

With that being said, I think your code should look like this:

```
$city  = $paramFetcher->get('city');

$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository(Category::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('a');
    ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Professionnel','p')
    ->where('p.city_id = :city')
    ->setParameter('city', $city);

return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Now the question: is that really just a `city_id` (plain integer) or is that relation to some entity named `City`?

Please update your question with those details and I will update the answer, if necessary...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For city, it's an entity and the relation with the professionnal is oneTomany (one city have many professionals). I tested this answer but it gives me the error: Cannot access private property Error::$previous

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that has nothing to do with the `QueryBuilder` issue...

Comment: I have this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p1_.city_id = '10873'' at line 1" It doesn't accept the 'where'. How can I translate the 'ON' of the 'leftJoin' with QueryBuilder?

Comment: Please update the question with latest code snippet. Also a snapshot of symfony logs would help...

Comment: I made the update of the code on the question. I thank you.

Comment: I found the error, I had to call the property 'a.professionnals' instead of 'App\Entity\Professionnel' on the second query. I thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need describe relations in entities. Read more about this [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

Secondary, you must call in join field (read as property), not a Entity.

inside CategoryRepository:

```
/** @return ArrayCollection|Category[] */
public function getByCityId(int $cityId): ArrayCollection
{    
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('category');
    $qb->leftJoin('category.professional', 'professional')
        ->leftJoin('category.city', 'city')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('city.id', $cityId));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Inside SomeController:someAction()

```
$cityId  = $paramFetcher->get('city');
$categoriesList = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
    ->getRepository(Category::class)
    ->getByCityId($cityId);
```

As result you'll be have list of category, with joined `professional` and `city`.
I suggest to read this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine.html) on symfony docs

Comment: City is an entity which have relation oneToMany with Professionnal. And Professionnal have ManyToMany relation with Category. So I want to show professionals who have this city_id groupedBy Category.

Comment: then I show right example. Look at @JovanPerovic response, he suggest a same solution

Comment: but it gives me the error: Cannot access private property Error::$previous

Comment: @Y.Coding you have error on some other place, look into trace what a full namespace of class Error? Where it was happen?

Comment: I have this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p1_.city_id = '10873'' at line 1"
It doesn't accept the 'where'.  How can I translate the 'ON' of the 'leftJoin' with QueryBuilder?

Comment: I found the error, I had to call the property 'a.professionnals' instead of 'App\Entity\Professionnel' on the second query. I thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Y.Coding in this cause i suggest use words in aliases, like `category` instead just `a`. It just one step to save you from mistakes.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. I want to know please how to show only categories which have professionnals with the condition, because It shows me even categories which have no professionnal.

Comment: I think is wrong mapping, type in terminal `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`, if you have no mapping errors put your file to gist and leave link here